Should I daemonize shell-like process with systemd and connect its StdIn/Out/Err to (pseudo)terminal and if, how?
I want systemd to daemonize a shell-like process (to be specific: an EPICS IOC) so that I the interface is accessible after it is started during booting. Usually, a specific watchdog is calling a shell script which uses script(1) to execute screen, which in turn uses the IOC-shell as terminal. But this watchdog should not be used in this instance.
I tried to simply write a .service, which executes the script, but that fails (the script uses ps, which fails with a syntax error).
Than I tried to call screen directly from the server, which fails, because screen can't find a terminal.
Than I tried to use script in the systemd service, but script can not find screen, then.
When I tried to better understand systemd, I found that a service can have its own StdIn/Out/Err assigned. So I am wondering:

Is it possible to start multiple IOCs as a shell, with their I/O streams connected to some (pseudo)terminals?
If it is possible, would it make sense?
How would something like that look like in systemd?

Here is the bash-script I usually use to start the IOCs:
#!/bin/bash

# Because of the following line, this script needs to be in the base directory of the llrfctrl-server
WD=$(dirname $(realpath $0))/iocBoot/iocChimeraTKApp
PID_FILE=$WD"/llrfctrl.pid"
LOG_FILE=$WD"/ioc.log"
CFG_FILE=$WD"/screen.cfg"
SCREEN_NAME="llrfctrl_gun"

function sscreen(){
  # Set TERM if not as expected
  if [[ $TERM != "xterm-256color" ]]; then
    export TERM=xterm-256color
  fi
  # Set environmental variable IOC_WD, used in screen.cfg
  if [[ $IOC_WD != $WD ]]; then
    export IOC_WD=$WD
  fi
  echo "screen ${*}" >> ${LOG_FILE}
  script -q -c "screen ${*} &>> ${LOG_FILE}" /dev/null
}

function start_ioc(){
  # Change to work directory. Needed to start ioc!
  cd $WD

  # Check if screen of the same name is already running
  if `sscreen -ls | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME`; then
    echo "Error: screen instance called "${SCREEN_NAME}" does already exist!" >> $LOG_FILE
    exit 1
  fi

  # Start screen
  sscreen -L -c $CFG_FILE -S $SCREEN_NAME

  # Write PID to PID-file
  LLRF_PPID=`screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -Q echo '$PID'`
  LLRF_PID=`ps --ppid $LLRF_PPID -o pid=`
  echo ${LLRF_PID##*( )} > $PID_FILE

  # Send initialsation script to ioc shell
  sscreen -S ${SCREEN_NAME} -p 0 -X stuff '"< start.ioc$(printf \\r)"'
}

function stop_ioc(){
  #Change to work directory
  cd $WD

  # Kill the IOC process
  kill `cat $PID_FILE`
}

# Check if pidfile exists and is not empty
if [[ ! -s $PID_FILE ]]; then
  echo "No PID file found! Ending script!" >> $LOG_FILE
  exit 1
fi

case $1 in
  start)
    if ps -p `cat $PID_FILE` &> /dev/null; then
      echo "Error: IOC is already running!" >> $LOG_FILE
      exit 1
    else
      echo "Starting IOC!" >> $LOG_FILE
      start_ioc
    fi
  ;;
  stop)
    if ps -p `cat $PID_FILE` &> /dev/null; then
      echo "Stopping IOC..." >> $LOG_FILE
      stop_ioc
      echo "IOC terminated!" >> $LOG_FILE
    else
      echo "Error: Can't stop IOC, process not running!" >> $LOG_FILE
      exit 1
    fi
  ;;
  restart)
    if ps -p `cat $PID_FILE` &> /dev/null; then
      echo "Stopping IOC..." >> $LOG_FILE
      stop_ioc
    fi
    echo "Restarting IOC..." >> $LOG_FILE
    start_ioc
    echo "IOC started!" >> $LOG_FILE
  ;;
  shell)
    if ps -p `cat $PID_FILE` &> /dev/null; then
      sscreen -rS $SCREEN_NAME
    else
      echo "No process running! Cannot attach non-existent screen!" >> $LOG_FILE
    fi
  ;;
  *)
    echo "Expects argument to be either start, stop or restart." >> $LOG_FILE
esac

and here the .service file:
[Unit]
Description=EPICS-based LLRF control server for the GUN

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/epics-servers/GUN/iocBoot/iocChimeraTKApp
Type=simple
Environment=TERM=xterm-256color
Environment=IOC_WD=/var/epics-servers/GUN/iocBoot/iocChimeraTKApp
ExecStart=/var/epics-servers/GUN/ioc start
# ExecStart=screen -L -c screen.cfg -S llrfctrl_gun
# ExecStartPost=screen -S llrfctrl_gun -p 0 -X stuff "<start.ioc\015"
# ExecReload=screen -XS llrfctrl_gun quit ; screen -L -c screen.cfg -S llrfctrl_gun ; screen -S llrfctrl_gun -p 0 -X stuff '<start.ioc\015'
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
TimeoutStartSec=60
TimeoutStopSec=30
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

PS:
I know procServ, but I want to explore other options, first.
